# TypeError: Cannot read property 'childNodes' of undefined at f (angular.min.js:62)at angular.min.js:62 "<div ng-view="" class="ng-scope">"

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing, ngroute

I have been facing this from a long time, it is thrown when I'm trying to bind data to a variable in the html using `{{}}`. I used `ngRoute` for routing among different pages. The above mentioned error occurs when I'm trying to bind data to a variable or `ng-model` in the HTML.

But it works fine when the model's value is already declared in the controller.

The data that I'm receiving is from a custom service, which eventually makes an http GET request upon calling it from a controller.

```
<html ng-app="bgpsApp">
<body>
    <div ng-view></div>
</body>
<!-- scripts loaded in a sequence: 
     jquery, angular.js(1.6.9), angular-route.js,  app.js, customservices.js -->
</html>
```

#### app.js

```
var bgpsapp = angular.module('bgpsApp', ['ngRoute']);
bgpsapp.config(function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
      templateUrl: 'brahmagpslogin.html'
    })
    .when('/portal', {
      resolve: {
        "check": function($location, $rootScope) {
          if (!$rootScope.logStatus) {
            $location.path('/');
          }
        }
      },
      templateUrl: 'portal.html'
    })
    .otherwise({
      redirectTo: '/'
    })
})

bgpsapp.controller('MainController', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$http', 'services', function($scope, $rootScope, $http, services) {
  services.getDashboardData($rootScope.master.userId).then(function(response) {
    $scope.vehiclesStatus = response.data.data.vehiclesStatus;
    console.log($scope.vehiclesStatus); 
    // ** assigning value to bind **
    $scope.vehicleCount = $scope.vehiclesStatus.vehicleCount;
  }, function(response) {
    alert(response.data.message);
  });
}]);
```

#### portal.html

```
<div id="wrapper" ng-controller="MainController">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-7 col-lg-7">
      <h4>Vehicles
        <small> Status</small>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-5 col-lg-5">
      <h4>
        <!-- trying to bind data to this variable -->
        {{vehicleCount}}
        <small>Trucks</small>
      </h4>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### custom service js

```
bgpsapp.service('services', function($http) {
  this.baseURL = "http://xxx/api/data";
  this.getDashboardData = function(customerId) {
    var d_response = {};
    var response = $http.get(this.baseURL + "/customer/data/dashboard?userId=" + customerId);

    return response;
  }
});
```

Comment: What was your console log data of **console.log($scope.vehiclesStatus);** line?

Comment: @ImmanuelKirubaharanS {idleWithLoad: 0,idleWithoutLoad: 4,runningWithLoad: 0,runningWithoutLoad: 2,vehicleCount: 6}

Comment: what's the version of `angular-route.js`?

Comment: @AlekseySolovey  v1.6.9